# Predicting future data with date

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, data-science-model

I have a data as below:

```
Date                                 Quantity   Rate      Value
01-Jan-18   0.5HP Motor Xcite        9 nos      2277.82   20500.39
02-Jan-18   0.5HP Pump Booster       1 nos      11648.30  11648.30
03-Jan-18   0.5 HP Trashmasher       1 nos      3390.70   3390.70
```

I want to predict the future value of the quantity/rate/value based on particular date for the given particular.  Which model can be used to predict the future value for the given particular for a given date in the future? (I am a R developer and just started and I don't know Python)

Comment: You can start with https://github.com/facebook/prophet, that has API in R

Answer (score 2):

You could use R to apply time series analysis to your data, i.e. as described [here](https://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/timeseries.html).

Comment: Thank you. It helps at high level. But I want to predict the data for a given date or date range.  Example: what will be my sales as on 30-Mar-19 or my sales between 15-mar-19 to 30-mar-19...  This means, the date wise display may be required in the forecast/prediction results...